# Modify handler of default button / Adding custom button in MediaControls UI in Android13

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-13

I'm developing a movie player app using Flutter.
As long as I know, from Android13, it introduce new styles in Media Controls at Lock Screen and Notification area.
Reference https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/media-control?hl=en

Now it is like this:

[image: Capture when I play video with Youtube app]

There is pause/play button. When user tap it, I want to do some process before the video player actually play/pause the video. (Actually it is permission check.)

So I'm looking for a way to modify handling the default button, or adding custom button to do it.

Does anybody know it?
Thanks for in Advance.